# How To call a rest API inside an Apache Flink program

Tags: rest, http, apache-flink

I m wondering if there is a solution to call a

1. REST API (or multiple REST APIs) inside a flink program **directly** or not ? if such solution is exist.
2. Do you think it is better to push my processed data from flink to a message broker like  kafka or something at first and then from kafka call REST APIs?
3. or I can Call REST APIs directly from my flink program as well?

Comment: "from Kafka call REST api" - not really clear how you'd make that work, but if you are in control of that server's code, you could embed a Kafka consumer rather than only accept REST

Comment: Thanks ,Very nice point. So you believe, Using Kafka consumer instead of rest api as endpoints which consumes processed data is more efficient in a streaming environment?

Comment: If you want to have a non-blocking, eventually consistent, reactive architecture, then yes

Answer (score 6):

The code in your user functions (e.g. a RichFlatMapFunction or a KeyedProcessFunction) can do anything you want, including making REST calls to external services. However, you should avoid doing blocking i/o in your user functions, because checkpoint barriers can't progress through an operator while it is blocked in the user function.

A good way to approach this then is to use Flink's [Async I/O API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html) in combination with an HTTP library that offers an asynchronous client interface.

Comment: Thanks alot. Would you please kindly write a simple code which demonestrate how can I call a rest api with using Async I/O?Thanks again

Comment: If you try rest + async i/o and get stuck, feel free to ask another question. But I do prefer the more event-driven architecture recommended by @cricket_007 anyway, if that's an option.